# pip3 gives CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: cmake, pip

I am trying to run pip3 install face_recognition. But it gives below problem for cmake.

```
Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Generator

    NMake Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    x64

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
```

pip3 version is 9.03, Python 3.7 and cmake 3.12.0-rc3. I don't have Visual studio. I don't have admin rights on my PC. Hence I downloaded the all the above packages, extracted and added their bin dir in path. Similar way I have installed MinGW and added its bin directory in path. Nothing is working. Couple of forums talk about removing CMakeCache.txt. I am struggling to find CMakeCache.txt. I think pip command is downloading the package, extracting in temp directory and compiling it. When compilation fails it delete the extracted content. Not sure.  Please help

Comment: Better to call pip from python interpreter e.g.: `python -m pip` if you don't have any rights use `--user` option.
BTW your problem is the cmake generator used -_-

Comment: The library is not officially supported on Windows, so it is not surprising. Have you read the user-provided instructions: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully studying a logs, I realized it's Dlib installation a giving problem.  
After lots of search, I got the url https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only. It suggest to use Anaconda. I installed the Anaconda and followed the instruction from article and discussions. It worked perfectly for me.